# Import external json file to package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, package.json

I have a module with extra configuration into package.json file

This configuration can grow a lot and I would like to put it in a separate file so I can import it to the package.json and get extra configurations from that file  (something like index config file).

Something like this:

external.json file:

```
{
    "moduleConf": {
      "some_conf": "dist/...",
      "some_conf2": "dist/...",
     }
}
```

And then import to package.json like this:

```
"my-module": "../external.json"
```

I have tried many configurations but none works for me

example of my Package.json

```
{
"scripts": {    
 "build-my-module": "cd src && copyfiles moduleConf/**/*.png moduleConf/**/**/*.png 
 moduleConf/**/*.html moduleConf/**/**/*.html ../dist/"
  },

 "main": "...js",
  "my-module": {
    "moduleConf": {
      "some_conf": "dist/...",
      "some_conf2": "dist/...",
        ...
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "my-module": "^0.0.0",
   },
  "dependencies": {
      ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm...CLI Builders can run shell commands. Maybe you can create a builder that synchronously runs such that you execute a shell command that grabs your "second" package.json file (or whatever file holds the additional config), put it in package.json where you want it, return the builder, and then let the angular build process continue? So basically you just run some file read/write commands at the top of the build process. Not posting it as an answer as I don't know if it'll work, but off the top of my head I don't immediately see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Check out "Workspaces in Yarn". Maybe this is what your are looking for.